# how to access several layers of dictionaries and lists nested within each other and collect them into a list

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pycharm

im looking to access the urls of the images in this json file. However I can only get so far in the nest. I got as far as Image which prints out ' "url": //images.... '

```
{
    "devices": [
        {
            "variants": 
            [
                {
                    "iMEIPrefix": null,

                    {
                        "totalTax": 0,

                    },
                    "smartTab": {
                        "payOffPeriod": 24,
                        "requiredUpfrontPayment": 0,

                    },
                    "pricingForUi": {
                        "payOffPeriod": 24,
                        "requiredUpfrontPayment": 0,

                    },

                    "memory": "64GB",
                    "phoneImages": [
                        {
                            "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/7bx5buq4osbe/4tfPcjBNmnbWupJ7byONiZ/0f27dc736403c4027bbf13f184ffd4fc/PIXEL3A-BLACK-FRONT.png",
                            "title": "PIXEL3A-BLACK-FRONT",
                            "description": null
                        },
                        {
                            "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/7bx5buq4osbe/1UVKkXIBCUPkKJ8ROvFkOO/8f25b2c57bfd774792dfb69ed1d3cc29/PIXEL3A-BLACK-SIDE.png",
                            "title": "PIXEL3A-BLACK-SIDE",
                            "description": null
                        },
                        {
                            "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/7bx5buq4osbe/1K2AP67ZhWb9pBtIp3r1sj/755bdc263d4a6e43e8275bea2beb92d3/PIXEL3A-BLACK-BACK.png",
                            "title": "PIXEL3A-BLACK-BACK",
                            "description": null
                        }
                    ],
```

## my code thus far

```
phoneImages = phone['variants'][0]['phoneImages']

data['image'] = phoneImages
```

for example im hoping to have this output:

```
"image": [                                      
    "https://xpressphone-backend.herokuapp.com/Apple iPhone XR/xr-black-front.png",
    "https://xpressphone-backend.herokuapp.com/Apple iPhone XR/xr-black-back.png"
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
urls = []

phoneImages = phone['variants'][0]['phoneImages']

for phoneImage in phoneImages:
  urls.append = phoneImage['url']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a valid json file, you should remove `{"totalTax": 0},` this part or convert into `"totalTax": 0`

```
data = {}
phoneImages = [image['url'] for image in phone['devices'][0]['variants'][0]['phoneImages']]
data['image'] = phoneImages
print(data)
```

O/P:

```
{'image': ['//images.ctfassets.net/7bx5buq4osbe/4tfPcjBNmnbWupJ7byONiZ/0f27dc736403c4027bbf13f184ffd4fc/PIXEL3A-BLACK-FRONT.png', '//images.ctfassets.net/7bx5buq4osbe/1UVKkXIBCUPkKJ8ROvFkOO/8f25b2c57bfd774792dfb69ed1d3cc29/PIXEL3A-BLACK-SIDE.png', '//images.ctfassets.net/7bx5buq4osbe/1K2AP67ZhWb9pBtIp3r1sj/755bdc263d4a6e43e8275bea2beb92d3/PIXEL3A-BLACK-BACK.png']}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help bharatk,
however i am now receiving a KeyError: 'devices'